# Writing Japanese in Latex2e

Tags: xetex, pdftex, japanese

A wonderful person has translated my free physics book into Japanese. Also the translation will be available for free. A typical part of the .tex file is:

> \label{specialrelat}運動の精密な記述には、光が不可欠である。線や運動径路がまっすぐかどうかを調べるには、その線や経路に沿ってながめる必要がある。言い換えると、「まっすぐ」を定義するのに光を用いる。面が平坦であるかどうかを見極めるにはどうすればいいのか。やはり、光を用いて面を見渡す。

I would like to typeset it on my Mac (OSX 10.6.8) using the standard CTAN TeX installation. What is the best way to proceed? Should I use XeLaTeX or pdflatex? How exactly? I am a longtime LaTeX2e user, but have never typeset Japanese.
When I type XeLaTeX or xelatex, the system answers:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) 
(preloaded format=XeLaTeX)
restricted \write18 enabled.
**
```

What is the exact command that I need to use to typeset the Japanese file (called J_MotionMountain-Part2.tex)? I absolutely need to follow the dvi-> ps -> pdf route.

There should probably be a command like XeLaTeX -.. J_MotionMountain-Part2.tex, then a comman using dvips (this I know how to do) and then one that makes the pdf (which I also know how to do). So the question is threefold:

(1) What is the exact command that makes dvi out of the .tex file?

(2) What format does it need?

(3) What packages and fonts do I need to load to make the system typeset properly?

For comparison, here are the shell commands (comments start with #) that I use for the English version that uses pdflatex:

```
# The .cls file contains the command \pdfoutput=0 requesting dvi output:
pdflatex motionmountain-volume2.tex
#
# The SUBJECT index is prepared here:
makeindex -s motionmountain.ist -o  motionmountain-volume2.ind motionmountain-volume2.idx
#
# The NAME index is prepared here:
makeindex -s motionmountain.ist -o  motionmountain-volume2.nad -t  motionmountain-volume2.nag motionmountain-volume2.nax
#
# This is the final pdflatex pass:
pdflatex motionmountain-volume2.tex
#
# This is the creation of postscript:
dvips -R -Poutline -G0 -j0 -o motionmountain-volume2.ps motionmountain-volume2.dvi
#
# This makes the pdf:
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER   -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dFastWebView=true motionmountain-volume2.ps  motionmountain-volume2.pdf
```

Comment: What happens if you type `which xelatex` in your Terminal? What does it say?

Comment: It says: /usr/texbin/xelatex

Comment: What editor do you use?

Comment: I work with editors that are separated from the tex system, and typeset everything using  a " bash japanesecommandfile.sh " command. So I usually just put all the shell commands I need, one after the other, in the file japanesecommandfile.sh and then run " bash japanesecommandfile.sh ".

Comment: can I ask why you need to follow the `dvi->ps->pdf` workflow as opposed to compiling directly into pdf?

Comment: @MotionMountain Wouldn't you need to do `japanesecommandfile.sh <yourfile>`? Also, if you shared the contents of your bash file in your question, we could test it. I don't think it's too long.

Comment: I have various reasons, including psfrag, eps images, the use of postscript macros, a running system since over 20 years, etc.

Comment: @Alenanno: yes, but which line has to be in there?

Comment: your document may be compiled using `xelatex` as a straight replacement of `latex` in your shell script, but then again  it might not. You may need to work a lot on your preamble to make the fonts or other bits. This is a problem with workflow that have been inherited from years of usage. xelatex should compile straight to pdf but in two integrated steps by creating an xdvi file first and then creating the pdf from that. it should run the dvixpdfm command internally so you should not need to run it yourself.

Comment: If your original bash script to compile the english version is not too long you might want to consider adding it to your question.

Comment: @MotionMountain Do you want `xelatex` or regular latex is fine, too? `xelatex` makes typing other languages easier, but it makes the production of a `.ps` file harder.

Comment: I do not need to type any more; the text file is ready. I just need to process it. Can I use "latex" for japanese?

Comment: @MotionMountain It depends, do you need the `.ps` part?

Answer (score 2):

In order to get a `.dvi` file you need to run `latex myfile.tex` in your terminal, but this is not going to work with `xelatex`. For this engine, you should run

```
xelatex -no-pdf file.tex
```

This will produce an `.xdv` file (an extended `.dvi`), however there is no "xdvtops", so your main choice becomes `pdftops` (which you might have to install separately). With it, after you converted `.xdv` to `.pdf` with `xdvipdfmx`, you'll be able to generate a `.ps`. So in summary,

for `latex` (**note** != `pdflatex`):

```
latex file.tex
dvips file.dvi
```

and for `xelatex`

```
xelatex -no-pdf file.tex
xdvipdfmx file.xdv
pdftops file.pdf file.ps
```

So that's the problem with your case: instead of `latex`, you're using `pdflatex` which won't produce a `.dvi`, but even if it did, it's not `xelatex` which you're requesting.

Comment: Can I use latex for japanese or do I have to use xelatex?

Comment: @MotionMountain You can, `xelatex` only makes it easier, and better, since it has better font handling, especially of non-Latin scripts.

Comment: @MotionMountain I can show you an example in `xelatex` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

**XELATEX**

XeLaTeX offers the possibility of importing external popular fonts or using the ones you already have in your Operating System:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{AozoraMinchoRegular.ttf}
\setCJKsansfont{KodomoRounded-Light.otf}
\setCJKmonofont{KodomoRounded-Light.otf}


\begin{document}

\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる

\vspace{0.5cm}

And you can also use Latin characters within your Japanese document.

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{verbatim}
このテキストは、別のフォントを持つことになります

This is a verbatim environment with mono-space font
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

As you see, to set up a LATEX document in Japanese is straightforward.

**PDFLATEX**

The CJTK package can also be used to generate a document with pdfLaTeX. External fonts can not be used, so compiling with XeLaTeX is recommended. With pdfLatex :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}
\section{これは最初のセクションである}
日本語で \LaTeX の組版を実証するための導入部分。

フォントはまた、数学的な形態および他の環境で使用することができる
\end{CJK}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent
Outside the environment Latin characters may be used.

\end{document}
```

The line `\usepackage{CJKutf8}` imports CJKutf8 which enables utf8 encoding for Chinese, Japanese and Korean fonts.

In this case every block of Japanese text must be typed inside a `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{min}` environment. In this environment UTF8 is the encoding and min is the font to be used. You can also use the JIS encoding with the song font

Comment: The question has more requirements than just typesetting Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it will work on Mac, but I use on Linux (texlive 2013) following template to make Japanese language tutorial

```
\documentclass{book}
\input{glyphtounicode} 
\pdfgentounicode=1 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[thaicjk,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{min}

日本語

\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

And compile it with pdflatex.

Comment: from the comments, the requirements for psfrag, eps, postscript macros and so forth, using pdflatex is probably not going to work here.